# Python Routes issues using Flask

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have the following function with multiple routes possible :

```
@bp.route('/list/', defaults={'status': None, 'time': None, 'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/', defaults={'status': None, 'search': None, 'time': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/', defaults={'status': None, 'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/<string:status>', defaults={'search': None})
@bp.route('/list/lot/<string:time>/<string:status>?search=<path:search>')
@login_required
def index(status, time, search):
    print(search)
```

All the routes works well, except the last one. I have the URL likes this :

```
http://192.168.10.88:5000/list/lot/OLDER/NEW?search=test
```

And I don't understand why, the print always return `None`.

Any ideas ?

Thanks